# Export all frames

Tags: python, split, export, xlsx, chunks

I have this code that splits a data frame into 2000 rows chunks, it is working, but when i export to an excel sheet, its only doing the last one frame, i need to keep all of them in the same file divided by sheets.

```
max_rows = 2000
dataframes = []
while len(df_count) > max_rows:
    top = df_count[:max_rows]
    dataframes.append(top)
    df_count = df_count[max_rows:]
    n=0
else:
    dataframes.append(df)

for _, frame in enumerate(dataframes):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output) as writer:
        frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= "DB" + str(n+1) , index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `n` with `_`

and you are reopening a new excel writer each time (you need to change the order of the loops):

```
max_rows = 2000
dataframes = []
while len(df_count) > max_rows:
    top = df_count[:max_rows]
    dataframes.append(top)
    df_count = df_count[max_rows:]
    n=0
else:
    dataframes.append(df)

with pd.ExcelWriter(output) as writer:
    for _, frame in enumerate(dataframes):
        frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= "DB" + str(_+1) , index=False)
```

Comment: It's still just exportin the last frame =(